# Display an EmguCV image in Windows Form Picture Box

Tags: c#, emgucv

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();  //line 1
CamImageBox.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
```

I have used above code for `Display` an `EmguCV` image in Windows Form Picture Box,

But I have got an error:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'system.drawing.bitmap' to
>   'emgu.cv.image'

This case also in Stackoverflow questions, but no one give proper answer for this.

Comment: I guess capture.QueryFrame() is a System.Drawing.Bitmap. You should try to load it like this: Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame =new Image<Bgr, Byte>(capture.QueryFrame());

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mix up the [PictureBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx) (provided by .NET framework in in System.Windows.Forms) and [ImageBox](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0-r16.12/document/html/859548b9-bada-0913-9e7c-65f60f3598e7.htm) (which is an EmguCV class in Emgu.CV.UI). Since both elements are very similar it's easy to mix them up.

> ImageBox is a user control that is similar to PictureBox. Instead of
>   displaying Bitmap, it display any Image<,> object. It also provides
>   extra functionality for simple image manipulation.

In your code sample your 'CamImageBox' element is an `ImageBox`. Adding a `Bitmap` to an `ImageBox` will indeed lead to the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to
>   'Emgu.CV.IImage'

The great thing about the `ImageBox` is that it provides you with additional features focused on EmguCV. One of these features is that you can directly show EmguCV `Image<,>` and `Mat` objects, which saves you a `ToBitmap()` convert. If you want to keep using the `ImageBox` element, either of the following two options are possible:

```
Mat matImage = capture.QueryFrame();
CamImageBox.Image = matImage; // Directly show Mat object in *ImageBox*
Image<Bgr, byte> iplImage = matImage.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
CamImageBox.Image = iplImage; // Show Image<,> object in *ImageBox*
```

**Please note**,

> as of `OpenCV 3.0`, IplImage is being phased out. EmguCV 3.0 is
>   following along. Image<,> is not officially deprecated yet, but keep
>   this in mind.

Therefore, please beware that in EmguCV 3.0 `QueryFrame()` will return a `Mat`! See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19119408/7397065

Also, your current code *will work* if you change the `ImageBox` element to a `PictureBox` element in your GUI.